# How to bring a possible topic for research to people's attention

Tags: research

I've noticed that a subgroup of patients with a particular disorder have an interesting diurnal pattern to their symptoms. As far as I can tell, this has not been covered in the literature (although there are studies that touch on the topic).

Sadly I am not a medical professional or scientist, so I can't take this anywhere myself.

Obviously at this point it is anecdotal. What could I do to bring this to the attention of someone who could potentially research it?

I had thought about collecting data through a survey, but as I am not affiliated with an institution this would be difficult. Could I find a graduate student to help me? Would this help me get traction with a medical researcher?

I must disclose that I have the disorder and the diurnal pattern, which is how I came to notice it.

And – you are free to disbelieve me – but I am not a crank, and have a bit of background in science as a keen layperson and former copy editor of health textbooks.

I know research ideas in science often spring from observations and "Hm, that's funny" moments and it seems to me that this could be one of those moments.

Comment: I would suggest studying the subject matter and finding out who the leading figures are in this field. Find out where they work, and contact them by their publicly available contact methods. Explain your question to them in a concise manner, and ask them if they have any interest in investigating your idea, and if not, who might.